# Should Django forms be populated on client-side when used as popus

Tags: javascript, django

My question is best described by example. 
Consider a table of students. When I click on a student, a pop-up should be opened with comprehensive info on the student. At first, each time the user clicks on a student, I did a GET-request via Ajax, and populated the pop-up with the fetched response. In other words, I did something like this:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET': 
        model_instance = MyModel.objects.get(id = request.POST['id']): 
        context = {'my_form': MyForm(instance = model_instance)}

        msg = render_to_string('my_template.html', context, request = request)
        return JsonResponse({'object': msg}, safe = False)
    else:
        # POST-request for saving input data to db
```

And then in the JS code:

```
$.get(....., function(response){
    $(response.object).modal('show');
}
```

The problem with this code is that the pop-up appears with a delay. Well, yes, it's half a second, and yet I would like the response to be instant. Especially, if the user has slow internet, user experience is even worse.

What is the best-practice here ? On alternative that occurs to me is the following: when rendering the main page (with student tables), pass an empty form (or as Django doc calls it, unbound form by doing `my_form = MyForm()`), and then populate it with JavaScript when the user clicks on a student. Well, this approach yields super-fast pop-up rendering, and yet the approach is not DRY, the case with ForeignKey fields is very nasty here, and in general, this approach seems junk code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Populating the form with JavaScript doesn't have to be ugly. I've done something like this before using HTML `data-` attributes to help keep things clean. If you're using jQuery, it could look something like this:

```
{% for student in students %}
<div class="student" data-student-id="{{ student.id }}" data-student-first-name="{{ student.first_name }}">
  {{ student.first_name }}
</div>
{% endfor %}

<!-- Pretend this is inside a modal -->
{{ form.as_p }}

<script>
$('.student').click(function() {
  var studentId = $(this).data('student-id');
  var firstName = $(this).data('student-first-name');
  $('#id_id').value = studentId;
  $('#id_first_name').value = firstName;
});
</script>
```

This assumes that `Student.id` is a [HiddenInput Widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#hiddeninput).
It doesn't take much JS to get you a pretty good result.